# PyMongo - Change output format

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

This is the MongoDB query which I was using in PyMongo to get the value:

```
query = [{"$match": {"scheduledAt": {"$gte": startTime, "$lt": endTime}}},
         {"$project": {"_id": "$type","countss": {"$cond": {"if": {"match$isArray": "$inputUrls"},"then": {"$size": "$inputUrls"},"else": "NA"}}}},
         {"$group": {"_id":"$_id","total_count":{"$sum": "$countss"}}}]
```

The output which I was getting:

```
[
  {_id: 'a', total_count: 3},
  {_id: 'b', total_count: 2}
]
```

Required output:

```
[
  {'a': 3},
  {'b': 2}
]
```

Comment: You might want to show 1 or 2 input docs to better contextualize how your nice query yielded the initial output.

Answer (score 2):

You need `$replaceRoot` stage as **last stage** with `$arrayToObject` to convert document into key value pair.

```
{
  "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": [
        [
          {
            k: "$_id",
            v: "$total_count"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pEbMoTBjKk3)